# How to solve this question. n^n =10^10^10. Solve for n.

Tags: calculus

I have tries solving by taking log on both the sides, but was unsuccessful. Please upgrade my knowledge.

Comment: There are two ways of reading "10^10^10". Please clarify if it is (10^10)^10 or 10^(10^10) - or [with formatting (useful link)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), $ (10^{10})^{10}$ or $ 10^{10^{10}}$

Comment: Is $n$ an integer?

Comment: Note that the exponentiation is not associative, $a^{\left(b^c\right)}\neq \left(a^b\right)^c$. In any case $n^n = m$ is equivalent to
$\exp\left(n\log n\right) = \exp\left(\log m\right)$ or to $n\log n=\log m$. The inverse function of $f(x)=xe^x$ is Lambert function $W(x)$, hence $f(\log n)=\log m$ leads to $n = \exp\left(W(\log m)\right)=\frac{\log m}{W(\log m)}$.

Comment: $$n=1\,105\,747\,502.593426$$

Comment: What's the calculus tag got to do with this?

Comment: @Joffan: Its 10^10^10 without any bracket, Later one in your comment.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$n^n=10^{(10^{10})}\\
n \log_{10}n=10^{10}$$
Now without the Lambert W function you won't get an exact solution.  [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n*log(10,n)%3D10%5E10) gives $n = e^{W(10000000000 \log(10))} \approx1.1$ billion.  You can find the numeric value by iteration.  We can guess that $n$ is about $1$ billion, then iterate $n=\frac {10^{10}}{\log_{10} n}$ to convergence.  We choose that form because $\log_{10}n$ is slowly varying, so the convergence will be rapid.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ross